# Changing form action based on text input

Tags: forms, text, input, action

So what I have is a simple search form and submit button. What I want to do is validate the input to determine whether or not an "=" was included in the search query, if so then I want it to send the input string (que) to vert.php. If not then I would like it to send to search.php.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function chgact()
   {
if(document.myform.que.indexOf(=) == true) {
   document.myform.action = '/vert.php';
   }
return true;
}
</script>
    <h1>Keyword search</h1>
    <form name="myform" method="post" action="/search.php"  onSubmit="return chgact()">
      Keywords: <br/>
      <input type="text" name="que" id="que" / >
      <p/>
      Items to display: <br/>
      <select name="i">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
      </select>
      <p/>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>
```

Any help at all would be so grealty appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line 4 to `if (document.myform.que.value.indexOf('=') != -1) {`

You need to get the **value** of que, you need to enquote the equals sign (you're searching for the **character** '='), and the `indexOf` function returns either -1 if not found or the position of the first occurrence, which is an integer. It does not return a boolean value.

Here is the updated code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function chgact()
   {
if(document.myform.que.value.indexOf('=') != -1) {
   document.myform.action = '/vert.php';
   }
return true;
}
</script>
    <h1>Keyword search</h1>
    <form name="myform" method="post" action="/search.php"  onSubmit="return chgact()">
      Keywords: <br/>
      <input type="text" name="que" id="que" / >
      <p/>
      Items to display: <br/>
      <select name="i">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
      </select>
      <p/>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: Okay so it returns the value as in -1 or 1 or 0 and puts that as the value of action is what you mean? I updated the code but it doesnt place vert as the action I thought that was what the myform.action = line did?

Comment: `indexOf` returns -1 if an equals sign was not found in the `que` textbox when you clicked the submit button. So, with the logic above, if `indexOf('=')` returns something other than -1 (meaning that the '=' character WAS found in the textbox), then it will switch the action to '/vert.php'. Copy and paste the entire above code and try it. It should work.

Comment: Awesome it does work, I appreciate you helping me out with the logic on that one. You mentioned that I had to pass the value to "que" along which I know is true but it seems it does have to be done in Javascript, am I right? Where would I be able to learn how that is coded?

Comment: `document.myform.que` gets you the text input **object**. `document.myform.que.value` gets you the **text** that was entered into the text input object. Before, your code wasn't checking to see if the **text** entered into the textbox contained an equals sign, your code was checking to see if the textbox **object** itself contained an equals sign, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I understand the answer it was a dumb mistake. I wondering how I can drop that text string into the url that this particular script changes the action to something like

Comment: document.myform.action = '/vert.php?id=        ('document.myform.que.value')

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that. When you submit the form, the value of the text input will automatically be passed. In your example, it will be passed via POST. No need to add it to the GET variables as well. But if, for some reason, you really want to to be passed by both POST and GET, `document.myform.action = "/vert.php?id="+ document.myform.que.value;`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you perform this action with PHP.  If your site visitor has JavaScript turned off, they won't get the benefit of your logic. I suggest you look at strpbrk() function to detect the "=" char.

Comment: What exactly would a script like this look like? I havent ever tried to use PHP for form validation.

Comment: I think that worrying about whether or not the browser supports Javascript is a thing of the past. I think it would be more detrimental to have to download an extra page from the server to determine where to redirect.

Comment: we are still getting about 11% of all site visitors with js turned off from 23 sites.  Consumers have a higher percentage of js enabled and medium and large corporations have a lower percentage.  I don't know about your filters here, but we are mindful of 11%.